# Calculator limits on a parabola

Tags: limits, conic-sections, calculator

Hi guys I'm making Patrick Star for a graphing project.

Anyways I'm using a parabola for his head on my TI-84 but when I set limits on it, it graphs a straight line.

So the equation itself is $y=(-0.5(x+1)^2+9)$ and I set limits to {$2.7$ is greater than $x$} and {$-6.9$ is less than $x$}

At $x=2.7$ it makes a horizontal line to infinity and at $x=-6.9! it makes another horizantal line to negative infinity.

Does anyone know how i can stop this?

Comment: try it with www.wolframalpha.com/ I'm pretty sure it's just a glitch in the inner mechanisms of the calculator to make calculation faster

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you did. If you were doing something like

```
Y = (-0.5(X+1)² + 9)(2.7>X)(-6.9<X)
```

then this will cause the value of `Y` to be zero when `X` is outside the selected range (because one of the two operators `>` or `<` will produce
the value $0$), but it will not make the value of `Y` be *undefined,* which is what you want.

You might try parametric graphing. For example:

```
X = T
Y = -0.5(T+1)² + 9
```

and for the `WINDOW` variables,

```
Tmin = -6.9
Tmax = 2.7
```

(Caveat: I'm inferring all of this from the TI-84 manual and from
hints at https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080612194029AAThWAe. I don't have the actual calculator on hand to try it, so you may
need to do a little experimenting.
For example, will the calculator allow you to set `Tmin` to a
negative number?)